# DatePicker in Sharepoint Search Refiner

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, display-template, refiner

I am trying to create a custom refiner that uses a begin and end date to filter my search results.
The problem is that i want the users to select those dates using a datepicker.

The problem i am facing is that my Jquery library is being loaded after my refiners.

I am using the

```
$includeScript(this.url, "url/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js");
```

and have got the

```
ctx.OnPostRender = [];
        ctx.OnPostRender.push(function () {
//Code
};
```

function inside of my display template
The jquery gets added to the sources when a user mouse over a search result. But this is to late.

Does anyone have any idea how to load the Jquery library together with the refiner.

Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this i just added the Jquery library to my master page. this way it got loaded before my webparts.